# Evaluating $\lim\limits_{x\to1}\frac{\sqrt[3]{x^3+1}}{\sqrt[3]{x+1}}$?

Tags: calculus, limits, radicals

This is the limit:

$$\lim_{x\to1}\frac{\sqrt[\large 3]{x^3+1}}{\sqrt[\large 3]{x+1}}$$

I made the calculation and the result gave $\sqrt[\large 3]{0}$, I wonder if this is the correct result, but if not, what would be the account to the correct result.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure it's $x\to 1$ and not $x\to -1$?

Comment: do you mean $x\rightarrow -1$ because otherwise this function is continuous and you get to just plug in.

Comment: Perhaps you have made an error. For $x^3+1 \to 2$ as $x \to 1$ *and* $x+1 \to 2$ as $x \to 1$. Your limit is $\sqrt[3]{2}/\sqrt[3]{2} = 1$.

Comment: Know the rules $\sqrt[n]{a}/\sqrt[n]{b}=\sqrt[n]{a/b}$ and $a^3\pm b^3=(a\pm b)(a^2\mp ab+b^2)$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\lim_{x\to-1}\frac{\sqrt[\large 3]{x^3+1}}{\sqrt[\large 3]{x+1}}=\lim_{x\to-1}{\sqrt[\large 3]{\frac{x^3+1}{x+1}}}=\lim_{x\to-1}{\sqrt[\large 3]{\frac{(x+1)(x^2-x+1)}{x+1}}}=$$

$$=\lim_{x\to-1}{\sqrt[\large 3]{(x^2-x+1)}}=\sqrt[\large 3]3$$

Comment: If $x\to1$ nothing to solve

Comment: The limit as $x\to-1$ is $3^{1/3}$, not $1$. The limit as $x\to1$ is $1$.